# Is a 1h 32m layover in ORD enough between a domestic arrival and international departure?

Tags: air-travel, airports, layovers, delays, chicago

I was wondering whether 1h 32m will be enough to change the planes in ORD to fly overseas (I won't have any checked bags). The flight is this:

[image]

Also, what happens if the first flight gets delayed or if this 1h 32m window will not be enough for security check, etc.? (And what procedures await me, if any, during this layover?) Will United replace my ticket free of charge?

Comment: Some anecdotal reference that might make you feel better: I've had a 45 minute layover in ORD (LAS-ORD, and ORD to somewhere in Europe) right before Thanksgiving a few years ago. There was some running involved, and it was really tight, but I made it.

Comment: @rainer: Did the baggage travel with you or they missed the connection?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: Forgot to mention that, even my baggage was transferred flawlessly :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a domestic-international connection such as this, you'll simply have to get yourself to the next gate. No other procedures or security checks are involved. ORD is a large airport, but 1:32 should be plenty of time unless your inbound flight is delayed. For example, today's UA1087 arrived at gate C31, while today's UA895 left from gate C18, just down the hall of the same concourse. That may not always be the case, but the gates will be connected without having to go through security, possibly through [the funky tunnel](https://viewfromthewing.boardingarea.com/2013/06/06/the-tunnel-between-uniteds-b-and-c-concourses-at-ohare/).

If there are delays and you do not make the Hong Kong flight, United will book you onto another flight free of charge, though you may be responsible for expenses in the meantime (such as a hotel room), particularly if the delay is caused by weather or another factor outside the airline's control. United only has the one daily flight from Chicago to Hong Kong, so if you miss it, an alternate routing could mean a significant delay.

It's absolutely doable if there aren't delays. Personally, I like to leave a longer buffer before connecting to infrequent long-haul flights, and it looks like there are a number of IND-ORD flights to choose from, so I might choose an earlier flight and a longer layover, but it comes down to your preference and tolerance for risk.

Comment: In addition: if you see that you first flight is delayed, ask UA representative. They may board you in rush on a earlier flight (possibly also delayed), or they will change your route, so that your delay will be reduced (and not too much time in Chicago). Earlier: UA has more options, airlines like to have options.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know whether I will only need to check in once (and how many boarding passes should I have - 1 or 2)?

Comment: @user76396 Since this is a single ticket, you should only need to check in once in Indianapolis, and you'll be given two boarding passes, one for each flight. You can also check-in with the United app, and if that process succeeds (it sometimes isn't available for international flights), you'll have your boarding passes electronically on your phone so you won't need to stop at the check-in counter at all. In any case, do not leave the secure area at ORD to go to the check-in counter there. Have a great trip!